# Define multiple entityManagerFactory bean using Spring Java @Configuration

Tags: spring, entitymanager, spring-data-jpa, jta, spring-java-config

I am using multiple databases in my system. I am using `AtomikosDataSourceBean` to enable xa distributed transaction among multiple dbs.

In `spring-configuration.xml` file I can create beans for two separate `EntityManagerFactory` let say entityManagerFactory1 and entityManagerFactory2. But when I do it using Spring Java `@Configuration`, I get error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
```

If I create one as entityManagerFactory and another as entityManagerFactory1 then I get error as

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.tom.boon.core.model.Person
```

for Enitities created under entityManagerFactory1.

Can someone help me in figuring out how to define two separte entityManagerFactory in a Spring Java @Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really provide that much detail about your configurations.  Assuming that those are fairly straightforward as they should be, then you have two beans defined: entityManagerFactory1 and entityManagerFactory2

You need to refer to these via @Resource as follows for the first usage:

```
@Resource(name =  "entityManagerFactory1")
EntityManager entityManager
```

and in the other usage:

```
@Resource(name =  "entityManagerFactory2")
EntityManager entityManager
```

This should work, unless something else is wrong.  If that is the case, please provide more details about what you are doing.  Hope this helps.

Comment: My question was different. Your answer is to how I would access two different entityManagers from one class. But I wanted to know how to define multiple entity managers in one Configuration Class.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file, make use the `persistenceUnitName` property as follows:

```
<bean id="foo" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceFoo"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="foo"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bar" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBar"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="bar"/>
</bean>
```

See how `dataSource`s are different for them. You can define different connection properties in `dataSourceFoo` and `dataSourceBar`. Then simply use:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "foo")
private EntityManager foo;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "bar")
private EntityManager bar;
```

and EntityManagers foo and bar should connect to different databases.

Do not forget, you need the `<context:annotation-config />` element in your configuration file if you want Spring to recognize `@PersistenceContext` annotation.